# Table inside of another

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to plan my trips publicly so other people can join me. So, I have set-up an PHP site.

I have this tables:

```
trips:
+----+---------+------------+------------+-------------------------+
| id | title   | date_start | date_end   | marker_adress           |
+----+---------+------------+------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | Berlin  | 2015-07-10 | 2015-07-11 | Potsdamer Platz, Berlin |
|  2 | Hamburg | 2015-07-16 | 2015-07-18 | Jungfernstieg, Hamburg  |
+----+---------+------------+------------+-------------------------+

fellows:
+----+---------+---------------+
| id | trip_id | twittername   |
+----+---------+---------------+
|  1 |       1 | prtyengopls   |
|  2 |       1 | itobi_yt      |
|  3 |       1 | jessisadancer |
|  4 |       2 | jessisadancer |
|  5 |       2 | woelfch3n     |
+----+---------+---------------+
```

For displaying sake, I want to query them in one query. **How can I query the database so I have something like this?** (I know, it's JSON but it shows the structure very well.)

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "date_start": "2015-07-10",
    "date_end": "2015-07-11",
    "marker_adress": "Potsdamer Platz, Berlin",
    "fellows": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "twittername": "prtyengopls"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "twittername": "itobi_yt"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "twittername": "jessisadancer"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @skroczek I know how to do "Basic Querys" but I've never done something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to use a `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT 
  t.id AS tripID, 
  t.title AS title, 
  t.date_start AS dateStart, 
  t.date_end AS dateEnd, 
  t.marker_address AS markerAddress,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(f.id AS CHAR)) AS fellowID,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(f.twittername AS CHAR)) AS twitterName
FROM trips t LEFT JOIN fellows f ON t.id = f.trip_id
GROUP BY t.id
```

By using this you will get a single row for each trip and you can loop over `fellowID` and `twitterName` for each row, as it will be `comma` delimited list like this:

```
fellowID: 1,2,3
twitterName: prtyengopls,itobi_yt,jessisadancer
```

> Edit 1: I got a new column to trips called checked which is a boolean.
>   Could you update your query, so only trips that have this boolean
>   toggled on are displayed?

```
SELECT 
  t.id AS tripID, 
  t.title AS title, 
  t.date_start AS dateStart, 
  t.date_end AS dateEnd, 
  t.marker_address AS markerAddress,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(f.id AS CHAR)) AS fellowID,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(f.twittername AS CHAR)) AS twitterName
FROM trips t INNER JOIN fellows f 
  ON t.id = f.trip_id AND t.checked = 1
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'f.id AS CHAR)) AS fellowID, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (CAST f.twittername AS CHAR)' at line 7`

Comment: I have modified the query. Try again.

Comment: Thank you, its working now for the first dataset (=>Berlin), but not for the following (=> Hamburg)

Comment: I got a new column to `trips` called `checked` which is a boolean. Could you update your query, so only trips that have this boolean toggled on are displayed? I have tried several things like `WHERE t.checked` or `WHERE t.checked = 1` (which is basicly the same)..

Comment: @jeyemgfx I have updated my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle?

Comment: `AND t.checked = 1` only hides the fellows (returning *null* in both fields) for the trip, but the whole trip is still there..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible like you expected in SQL. Just to answer your question and show you the problem: you have to use a join (left, inner or something ... depends of your database structure; I always prefer left joins if possible) to get all information in just one query:

```
SELECT * FROM trips t LEFT JOIN fellows f on t.id = f.trip_id WHERE t.id = 1;
```

But you always will get the trip information with every row, and for that you have to process it afterwards. You will never able to select such a nested structure, you will always get a flat one.
So I would recommend to split it into two queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM trips WHERE id = 1;
SELECT * FROM fellows WHERE trip_id = 1;
```

You will have to process the information afterwards too, but you just select the wanted information from your database.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, this may work as well, but I want to do as less db-handles as possible. I'm sorry, I don't have a photo for you today.